# Calculating Price/ 30-minutes in 24hour format

Tags: algorithm

I'm developing an algorithm for an Booking-System idea, and am stuck while calculating price.

I'm using a simple array that divides 24 hours to 48 intervals of 30 minute each.

```
$interval = {
0000, 0030, 0100, 0130, 0200, 0230, 0300, 0330, 0400, 0430, 0530, 0600,
0630, 0700, 0730, 0800, 0830, 0900, 0930, 1000, 1030, 1100, 1130, 1200,
1230, 1300, 1330, 1400, 1430, 1500, 1530, 1600, 1630, 1700, 1730, 1800,
1830, 1900, 1930, 2000, 2030, 2100, 2130, 2200, 2230, 2300, 2330 }
```

I've achieved so far using the help of my programmer friend, but am stuck in one line where I need to find how many intervals (of 30 minute each) lie in the chosen duration.

```
$cost = 0;
$checkin_seconds = $checkin * 3600;

//MAIN PRICES ARE DECLARED HERE
for( $i=0;      $i<48;      $i++ ) {        
    if $checkin=$interval[i]   {
        $array_index_number=i;  }   //checkin time index_number from array


for( $start=$checkin;   $start<$checkout;   $start+30 ) { 

//PROBLEM: $start+30 will not work as computer doesn’t know we’re dealing with time, you will have to improvise here

$total_intervals++;  }  // total number of 30 mins intervals

$count=0;
for( $var=$array_index_number;  $var < $var + $total_intervals; $var++ ) { //check against those indexes
    if( $array[$var]>= 0000  &&  $array[$var]<=0400 ) {      //prices for 12AM to 4AM
                    $count++;  }
    $price = 2250 / 2;          //price for 60 minutes
$cost = $cost + ($price * $count);      }   // cost for intervals that lie in 12AM to 4AM

$count=0;
for( $var=$array_index_number;  $var < $var + $total_intervals; $var++ ) { //check against those indexes
    if( $array[$var]>= 0400  &&  $array[$var]<=0800 ) {      //prices for 4AM to 8AM
                    $count++;  }
    $price = 2500 / 2;          //price for 60 minutes
$cost = $cost + ($price * $count);      }   // cost for intervals that lie in 12AM to 4AM

$count=0;
for( $var=$array_index_number;  $var < $var + $total_intervals; $var++ ) { //check against those indexes
    if( $array[$var]>= 0800  &&  $array[$var]<=1600 ) {      //prices for 8AM to 4PM
                    $count++;  }
    $price = 1800 / 2;          //price for 60 minutes
$cost = $cost + ($price * $count);      }   // cost for intervals that lie in 8AM to 4PM

$count=0;
for( $var=$array_index_number;  $var < $var + $total_intervals; $var++ ) { //check against those indexes
    if( $array[$var]>= 1600  &&  $array[$var]<=2000 ) {      //prices for 4PM to 8PM
                    $count++;  }
    $price = 2000 / 2;          //price for 60 minutes
$cost = $cost + ($price * $count);      }   // cost for intervals that lie in 4PM to 8PM

$count=0;
for( $var=$array_index_number;  $var < $var + $total_intervals; $var++ ) { //check against those indexes
    if( $array[$var]>= 2000  &&  $array[$var]<=2400 ) {      //prices for 8PM to 12AM
                    $count++;  }
    $price = 2250 / 2;          //price for 60 minutes
$cost = $cost + ($price * $count);      }   // cost for intervals that lie in 8PM to 12AM
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) operations work well with time problems. This solution assumes you are only working with ints, apply floor functions as necessary.

To calculate which time interval:

```
timeIntervals = 2*(timeNum / 100) + ((timeNum % 100) / 30)
```

So what you are looking for is:

```
totalIntervals = (2*(checkout / 100) + ((checkout % 100) / 30)) - (2*(checkin / 100) + ((checkin % 100) / 30))
```

Comment: What does (timeNum % 100) / 30) do? I don't know the % part.

Comment: That is the modulo operator, it's like the remainder of division. For example, 1030 % 100 = 30.

Comment: Thank you.
If possible, can you spend a few minutes to see if the remaining code is doing what its intended to?

Comment: Looks fine. A little over complicated. Try one for loop...      $cost = 0;
for( $var=$array_index_number;  $var < $var + $total_intervals; $var++ ) {
    if( $array[$var]>= 0000  &&  $array[$var]<=0400 ) {
        cost += 2250 / 2;
    } else if( $array[$var]>= 0400  &&  $array[$var]<=0800 ) {
        cost += 2500 / 2;
    }
}

Comment: Thanks for your time and the code. However, I'm going through it again and again, but I'm unable to see if 'for( $var=$array_index_number;  $var < $var + $total_intervals;  $var++ )' is enough to repeat the loop until all the intervals have been covered.

You do realize that if there are 6 intervals (3 hours), the code has to check for a cost against them for every individual interval?

Comment: Okay, 
I believe unless[ $var = $var + $total_intervals; ], the for loop will keep running. That means, even if several intervals lie in the same pricing scheme, they'll be charged individually.

Thank you, I get it now.